# $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ contains a unique subfield $K$ of degree $10$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\zeta$ be a $151$th root of unity, $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. How do I see that the cyclotomic field $L$ contains a unique subfield $K$ of degree $10$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Can we conclude that $\mathcal{O}_K$ has more than $3$ generators over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The galois group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{151}^*$, which is cyclic - the rest follows from properties of cyclic groups.

Comment: Isn't the second question trivial, since the rank of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is $[K:\mathbb Q]$ ?

Comment: I don’t understand your last question. Are you speaking of the $\Bbb Z$-rank of the integers of $K$, or are you asking about elements that generate that ring as a $\Bbb Z$-algebra, or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$L/\mathbb Q$ is a Galois extension with cyclic Galois group. Thus, there is exactly one subgroup for each divisor of the order of the Galois group. Therefore, there is exactly one intermediate field of each divisor of the degree of $L/\mathbb Q$. Since this degree is $\phi(151)=150$, $10$ is allowed.